# How to get JFrame object movement in another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So, I have a class Window which *extends* `JFrame`, which is the larger window.

[image]

Then I have class `MathematicalFunvtions` which also *extends* `JFrame`, which is the smaller window.

I want to combine them together in another class "Test" so they work together.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {       
    Window mainwindow;
    mainwindow = new Window();
    mainwindow.setVisible(true);


    MathematicalFunctions functions;
    functions = new MathematicalFunctions(mainwindow);
}
```

My way to do this is to give a reference of Window object as an argument to `MathematicalFunctions` and let it do the work.

1. Question is... is it a good way of programming things?
2. When I send *mainwindow* to *functions* I would like to know inside that object, when main window is moved... so this object can track it and adjust to so they are always together.

Comment: Please use proper naming for class names. `window` should be `Window` because it can be confused with a variable.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Also, it's usually better to *use* a `JFrame`, rather than *extend* one.

Comment: When you click poperties or options in some program then opens another window, photoshop layout is few windows on each side interacting together... so they are not JFrames?

Comment: Okey... I see it should be better JDialog. However I stil dont know   how to get movement of JFrame object in another class...

Comment: Maybe you want to call [`setType(Window.Type.UTILITY)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setType-java.awt.Window.Type-) on your secondary window (see [`Window.Type.UTILITY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.Type.html#UTILITY))…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt give up on research and finally i get it... i put this code in constructor of MathematicalFunctions:

```
mainwindow.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
            GlowneComponentMoved(evt);
        }
    });

//and the listener....
private void GlowneComponentMoved(ComponentEvent evt) 
{
      this.setLocation( (Okno_Glowne.getX()+ Okno_Glowne.getWidth()+10), Okno_Glowne.getY());   
}
```

and it works how it should be. Every time i move bigger window, the small one follows :)

Whats more...
Also Ive made MathematicalFunction class JDialog extension

```
public class MathematicalFunctions extends javax.swing.JDialog
```

and the test class looks like before

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

   oknoo mainwindow;
   mainwindow = new oknoo();
   mainwindow.setVisible(true);


   MathematicalFunctions funkcje;
   funkcje = new MathematicalFunctions(OknoGlowne);
}
```

;)